# SSH problem after ubuntu update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Setting up openssh-server (1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) ... Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ... Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ... start: Job failed to start

can't inicialize ssh, already tried reinstall.

netstat -tlnp shows that no service is running on tcp port 22

Comment: Going to the basics... are you running as root or using sudo when you try to start it? Did you edit the configuration file and now there are possible errors in the configuration? What command did you run to get the output you posted above? Have you checked your log files?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that my solution is right. But if you just want to start your SSH server and then solve your problem later, here is my fast solution:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- -p 22
```

if then you will see error:

```
Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd
```

then just create that missing directory, and try above *start-stop-daemon* command again:

```
mkdir /var/run/sshd
chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd
```

that helped me to start my sshd daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You've not provided much information but some common reasons why a service fails to start are:

- If there is something already listening on port 22; Do a `netstat -tlnp` to see if there is something listening on port 22.
- If there is insufficient memory. Do a `free -m` to ensure that there is sufficient memory free.

You can possibly try starting it manually to see if it works or shows more error messages. Check your log files.

Run `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` to see.

Comment: running it manually says the same thing more: you can use upstart to start ssh, start ssh, but gives the same error, with service it give the same error too

Comment: What does the netstat and free show?

Answer (score 1):

If your machine is a VPS which runs in an OpenVZ container, then try to comment out the "oom never" line in the /etc/init/ssh.conf file.